# Output table to excel tab even when there is no data

Tags: export-to-excel, powerbi-paginated-reports

I am exporting a report to an excel file from a Paginated Report (Power BI version). There are 4 tables that are being output to their own excel tab using a page break. The end users what to always have 4 tabs, even if one of the tables has not returned data - so it would output an empty tab.

Anyone know how force Paginated report to output an empty table to excel tab?

1. I tried setting the Hidden property to FALSE = did not work
2. Created expression for Hidden property [=IIf(CountRows() = 0, False,False)], got the table to display empty, but on export to Excel, it only output the 3 tabs with the empty table at the top of the third tab